# How to redirect page after ajax complete?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-4

My ajax is performing successfully because it deletes the row from database :

```
    @Controller
    ...
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxDeleteUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView ajaxDelUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
        int userId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        userDao.delete(userId);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }
    ...
```

At the view :

```
<c:url value="/" var="home" scope="request" />
$.ajax({
        data: {"id":data},
        type: "POST",
        url:  "${home}"+"ajaxDeleteUser",
        async: false
});
```

The problem is that after the `ajax` is complete then I saw the row on the list ! So how to redirect to the list actual page after `ajax` complete ?

**UPDATE :**

Here is servlet-context.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ambre.hib" />

</beans:beans>
```

And here is web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider using "success" event: http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

```
$.ajax({
        data: {"id":data},
        type: "POST",
        url:  "${home}"+"ajaxDeleteUser",
        async: false,
        success: function(result) {
            location.href = "your_location"
        }
});
```

Comment: @pheromix try "error" event instead of "success", perhaps your request doesn't succeed

Comment: What does it mean "doesn't work", though? Did you check your browser's console, is there anything in logs?

Comment: ok , I found the source of the problem : I set the href attribute value of the link which launches the ajax to be '#'.

Comment: that is because you need to change the return type to a String and return the name of the page you want to redirect to in the ajax

Answer (score 1):

You've got two options here. First, you can redirect on the front end after the ajax completes using the ajax success function like below:

```
success: function(result) {
            location.href = "your_location"
        }
```

Or preferably you can do it on the backend using spring mvc do the job. For this purpose remove the @Responsebody cuz you don't need it (you are not returning anything) and also change the return type to a String like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxDeleteUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String ajaxDelUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
    //your stuff goes here
    ....
    //important line
    return "redirect:/index.html";
}
```

Here I am using index.html but change the name to your preferred page. As long as you've configured the Spring view resolver properly then it should work by itself. If you've put a suffix in the view resolver (for example .jsp) then you should  return just the name of the page without the suffix and spring will figure out the page automatically like below

```
return "redirect:/index";  //equals index.jsp
```

Comment: the method returning string in controller does not work !

Comment: post your spring webconfigurer, have u got a viewResolver? What error are u getting?

Comment: does it hit the controller at all? if you put a brakepoint in the controller, does it go there? What is that "${home}"+"ajaxDeleteUser"? what is ${home} in the ajax request

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this.This will redirect after response has arrived.

```
$.ajax({
    data:{"id":data},
    type: "POST",  
    url:  "${home}"+"ajaxDeleteUser",  
    async: false,  
    success: function(result) {  
        var link = "http://www.sample.com";    
        $(location).attr('href',link);  
    });
```